# Is it possible to create efficient recombining trees using (co)recursion?

Tags: haskell, recursion, binary-tree, recursion-schemes

By co-recursion I mean unfolding a tree, such as with `ana`morphism from Ed Kmett's [recursion-schemes](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes)

By re-combining trees I mean graphs that share structure. For example, a binomial [option pricing tree](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/b/binomialoptionpricing.asp), or [Pascal's triangle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle). Both of these have some symmetry, so for efficiency, we would like to avoid re-calculating part of the tree, instead re-using the already-calculated branches.

n.b. this question is *not* about some clever way to calculate the values in aforementioned examples; it's a general question about recursion.

For example, for options pricing, the tree can be generated like so:

```hs
data Tree x = Leaf x | Branch x (Tree x) (Tree x)
ana \(x, depth) ->
  if depth == maxDepth
    then LeafF x
    else BranchF x (p * x, depth + 1) ( (1.0 - p) * x, depth + 1)     -- p < 1.0
```

So the value in an 'up' branch is `p * x` and the value in a 'down' branch is `(1-p) * x`. Because of this symmetry, an 'up' followed by a 'down' node will have the same value as a 'down' followed by an 'up' branch. As will it's entire sub-tree.

I think it may be possible to do this passing along `State` that contains a hashmap of already calculated nodes somehow.

Or if I could somehow access the already-calculated subtree, I could pass it in as a `Left` in an `apo`morphism.

Is there some existing morphism that allows this? Or can I code my own?

Comment: The typical way to do dynamic programming in haskell is to store *all* (usually infinitely many) intermediate values in a lazy data structure, leveraging the runtime system's statefulness in evaluating thunks, rather than modeling statefulness explicitly. See [memoization](https://wiki.haskell.org/Memoization#Memoization_with_recursion) .  I suspect this can be adapted to a recursion combinator and it will be pretty :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ana` defines a recursive function `x -> Tree a` (given a coalgebra `alg :: x -> TreeF a x`). You can define a memoized version of `ana` by using a specialized fixpoint operator (whereas the usual definition is more or less equivalent to using `fix`), for example, as found in the [MemoTrie library](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/MemoTrie-0.6.10/docs/Data-MemoTrie.html#v:memoFix).

```hs
memoFix :: (...) => ((a -> b) -> (a -> b)) -> (a -> b)
-- for some constraints "(...)" depending on the implementation.
```

```hs
-- ana': Memoized version of ana

type Memo a b = ((a -> b) -> (a -> b)) -> a -> b

memoAna :: Memo x (Tree a) -> (x -> TreeF a x) -> x -> Tree a
memoAna memo alg = memo $ \ana_ x ->
  case alg x of
    LeafF a -> Leaf a
    BranchF a x1 x2 -> Branch a (ana_ x1) (ana_ x2)

ana' :: HasTrie x => (x -> TreeF a x) -> x -> Tree a
ana' = memoAna memoFix
```

This ensures all trees generated from the same seed `x` will in fact be the same tree.

You also have to be a little careful with the type of seed. In your example, with `(Double, Int)`, the imprecision of `Double` operations makes memoization unreliable. So you also need to modify the algebra. For example, since the price is always of the form `p^i (1-p)^(depth-i)`, you could remember the index `i` instead.

```hs
optionsAlg' :: Num a => a -> (Int, Int) -> TreeF a (Int, Int)
optionsAlg' p (ups, depth) =
  if depth >= maxDepth then
    LeafF price
  else
    BranchF price (ups+1, depth+1) (ups, depth+1)
  where
    price = p ^ ups * (1 - p) ^ (depth - ups)
```

Implementations of memoization have various trade offs. Depending on your particular use case, further optimizations and more adaptation may be necessary.